# Good approach to raise an exception

Tags: ruby, locking, exception

I have class `House` and module `Lockable`.  Locking and unlocking `House` should reflect the real world, so you can't lock twice.

Do you think this is a good approach to using a module and raising an exception?

```
module Lockable
  attr_reader :locked

  def lock!
    raise StandardError, "Already locked" if @locked == true
    @locked = true
  end

  def unlock!
    raise StandardError, "Already unlocked" if @locked == false
    @locked = false
  end
end

class House
  include Lockable
end
```

Usage:

```
house = House.new
house.lock!
house.unlock!
house.unlock! # raise an exception
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would define domain specific error classes like so:

```
module Lockable
  Error           = Class.new StandardError
  AlreadyLocked   = Class.new Error
  AlreadyUnlocked = Class.new Error

  def lock!
    raise AlreadyLocked if locked?
    @locked = true
  end

  def unlock!
    raise AlreadyUnlocked unless locked?
    @locked = false
  end

  def locked?
    # unless already defined, this assumes an
    # initial unlocked state (!!nil == false)
    !!@locked
  end
end
```

By having a common ancestor (`LockedError`), users can simply catch that one if they don't care about the inner state of the lockable object:

```
begin
  house.lock!
  house.lock!
rescue Lockable::Error
  # meh...
rescue StandardError
  # $! needs handling
end
```

*On the other hand*, if I try to lock an already locked lock, the key just won't move (and the lock doesn't blow up in my face). So, a more realistic reflection of the world would be this implementation:

```
module Lockable
  def lock!
    @locked = true
  end

  def unlock!
    @locked = false
  end
end
```

Comment: Just curious, is there a difference beteween `Error = Class.new StandardError` and `class Error < StandardError; end`?

Comment: It is one char shorter. Other than that, they're [equivalent](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Class.html#method-c-new). I personally don't like Ruby one-liners when they contain an ";". Declaring an error class should be a one-liner, hence the `Class.new` assignment.